# wordpress ajax form i found 404 when i submit it

Tags: ajax, wordpress, forms

i found 404 error
var endpoint='';
var bookingform=$("#BookingForm").serialize();

```
           jQuery.ajax({
                url: endpoint,
                type: "POST",
                data:{'action':'submitform1','bookingform':bookingform},
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (result) {
                     $("#propertydata").html(dat.data)
                },
                error: function(dat1){
                alert("error");

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending ajax to empty URL -> var endpoint='';

You need to send it to wordpress ajax url like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var endpoint = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
</script>
```

You need to paste the above code in header.php file of your theme.

Secondly, in the success function, you are using the variable that is not defined (dat) you need to use something like this:

```
   jQuery.ajax({
                    url: endpoint,
                    type: "POST",
                    data:{'action':'submitform1','bookingform':bookingform},
                    success: function (result) {
                         var dat = JSON.parse(result);   
                         $("#propertydata").html(dat.data)
                    },
                    error: function(dat1){
                    alert("error");
    
                }
});
```

Comment: its working fine but when i put file element its show 404 error $('#BookingForm').on('submit', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var fileInputElement = document.getElementById("uploadfile");
        var fileName = fileInputElement.files[0].name;
        alert(fileName);

Comment: If you want to upload a file using ajax in Wordpress, try this answer https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/263934/161862